# ListView показывать элементы относительно выбранной "категории"

Tags: android, база-данных, listview

Нужно что бы при выборе одной категории показывались элементы данной категории. То есть есть условное меню, где можно ее выбрать. Наверное можно менять активити относительно категории, но это не рационально. Основная проблема - это то, что при смене ArrayList в адаптере меняется и лист в главной активити, и все обновляется и никак не получается сохранить исходное количество элементов и сами элементы списка.

Вот выпадающие меню.

```
public void showPopup() {

    View menuItemView = findViewById(R.id.action_sort);
    PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(MainActivity.this, menuItemView);
    MenuInflater inflate = popup.getMenuInflater();
    inflate.inflate(R.menu.popup, popup.getMenu());


    popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {

            ArrayList<Item> list = new ArrayList<Item>();

            switch (item.getTitle().toString()) {
                case "Zerg":
                    list.clear();
                    for (Item item1 : array_build)
                        if (item1.Race == 0)
                            list.add(0, item1);
                    break;
                case "Protoss":
                    list.clear();
                    for (Item item1 : array_build)
                        if (item1.Race == 1)
                            list.add(0, item1);

                    break;
                case "Terran":
                    list.clear();
                    for (Item item1 : array_build)
                        if (item1.Race == 2)
                            list.add(0, item1);
                    break;

            }

            adapter.listChange(list);

            return true;
        }

    });

    popup.show();

}
```

Адаптер и метод обновления списка. На самом деле очень простой адаптер. listChange менять данный список на пришедший.

```
public class ItemAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    Context cnt;
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
    ArrayList<Item> itemlist;

    ItemAdapter(Context cnt, ArrayList<Item> itemlist) {
        this.cnt = cnt;
        this.itemlist = itemlist;
        layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) cnt.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return itemlist.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Item getItem(int position) {
        return itemlist.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = convertView;

        if (view == null) {
            view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_style, parent, false);
        }

        Item item = getItem(position);
        ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle)).setText(item.Title);
        ImageView image = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.ImageViewRace);

        switch (item.Race) {
            case 0:
                image.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.z);
                break;
            case 1:
                image.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.p);
                break;
            case 2:
                image.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.t);
                break;
            default:
                image.setBackgroundResource(R.color.black);
        };
        return view;
    }

    public void listChange(ArrayList<Item> list){

        itemlist.clear();
        itemlist.addAll(list);
        this.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }

    public void add(Item item1){
        itemlist.add(0,item1);
        this.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void remove(int position){
        itemlist.remove(position);
        this.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

И вот что получается при выборе одной из 4 категорий(Выбрал Protoss):
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А если выбрать еще одну то, по понятным причинам, у нас остается только этот список, а старый где хранились все остальные элементы пропал,как сохранить тот список после изменений в адаптере. Сама проблема, просто я пишу 3 денб, новичок. Если что все элементы в БД хранятся.
Выбрал Zerg:

Comment: Если данные хранятся в БД, используйте CursorAdapter и делайте выборку напрямую из БД. Зачем эти ArrayList нужны вообще, бессмысленное переливание в порожнее.